# Intermediate CA certificate has no valid signature

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509

I've followed the [Jamie's tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8sas.jpg) to create CA root and Intermediate CA certificates over Win7 using -subj option for subject info and they passed the openssl verify command with OK.

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out intermediate/private/intermediate.key.pem 4096
openssl req -config intermediate/openssl.cnf -new -sha256 -key intermediate/private/intermediate.key.pem -out intermediate/csr/intermediate.csr.pem -subj "/CN=AC Pruebas Inter (4096)/O=ORG S.A. de C.V./OU=Org unit/emailAddress=testinterca@org.com.mx/streetAddress=myStreet, myNumber/postalCode=09999/C=MX/ST=my City/L=my Locality/2.5.4.45=ORG990701NN3/1.2.840.113549.1.9.2=Responsable: ORG"
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -extensions v3_intermediate_ca -days 3650 -notext -md sha256 -in intermediate/csr/intermediate.csr.pem -out intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem
```

Then I renamed Inter CA certificate extension to .CRT in order to open it with windows client app, but in Certification path Tab at the status certificate field, it shows an error message saying that the certificate has no valid signature. I've installed the CA root certificate in the trusted root certificate store but the error message remains.

[image]

Which could it be the problem?

Comment: You've blurred the image, but I assume you checked the root/parent 'found' in the Certification Path = Ruta de Certificacion is the correct one. One **possibility** I can think of: the Windows is **Server 2003**, which didn't support sha256-RSA signatures, but S03 is officially dead. XP SP2 also didn't support sha256, but XP SP3 did and was strongly pushed out well before it EOLed, whereas the S03 hotfix wasn't even 'recommended' IIRC.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Nevermind, I was installing root cert in the wrong way using the Install button of windows client. The correct way is described in this [MS TechNet paper](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx) using MMC Windows Utility. Just for the record, I'm using Windows 7 dev machine, thanks anyway.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I was installing root cert in the wrong way using the Install button of windows client. The correct way is described in this [MS TechNet paper](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx) using MMC Windows Utility. Once the root cert was correctly installed the error message dissapeared.